# NoClassDefFoundError with Google Contact API V3

Tags: java, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to do some test with the Google Contact API V3 (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/). I'm just trying to authenticate and get every contacts from one account.

I've added in my lib the following jars:

- gdata-client-1.0.jar
- gdata-base-1.0.jar
- gdata-contacts-3.0.jar
- mail.jar

I downloaded the first two jars from: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjava%2Flib

When I try to run my code I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com/google/gdata/util/Version

In the gdata-client-1.0.jar there is a package util, but I cannot find the Version class.

Has anyone deal with this problem?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot `gdata-core-1.0.jar`